# Matrices - Find the value(s) of constant k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the values of the constant $k$ such that $(k$A$)^T(k$A$) = 28$, where:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$$

Actually, I got no idea how to solve this. 
how do i solve this?
Can you please offer your assistance? Thank you

Comment: What have you actually tried to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take the transpose of a vector multiplying the vector itself, you are dotting the two vectors.  So we have,

$$(kA)^T(kA)=k^2(1+4+9)=k^2(14)=28$$

So $k=\pm \sqrt{2}$

Comment: I left our a few of the steps so you can do the details if you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Do you know how to multiply matrices?

$$k^2 \begin{bmatrix}-1 \,\, 2 \,\, -3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\-3\end{bmatrix} =8$$

Comment: You might want to give this answer a second look.

Answer (score 0):

Try actually multiplying it out and seeing what you get.

$(KA)^T = \begin{bmatrix}-1K,2K,-3K\end{bmatrix}$

$(KA) = \begin{bmatrix}-1K\\2K\\-3K\end{bmatrix}$

Thus when they are multiplied using vector/matrix multiplication you get:

$K^2 +4K^2+9K^2 = 28$

$K^2(1+4+9)=28$

$K^2=2$

$K=\sqrt2$

Comment: This is off topic of the problem, but you should learn how to use LaTex at some point.  It's really nice!  I use it all the time in my graduate studies, and LaTex commands are what to use to get fancy looking stuff :)

Comment: Could you post a link to these LaTex commands?  That would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So this link is something I just found that is essentially just a huge list of commands http://www.ntg.nl/doc/biemesderfer/ltxcrib.pdf  If you know someone who can use Latex, they would be a better source.  Or just google specific symbols you need.  Good luck!